# Jquery/Js - Get current url between the slashs to get the accordion collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, url, accordion

I have 2 different url which are:

1. index.php?r=admin/plan/list
2. index.php?r=admin/user/list

And 2 accordion which have the id="user" and id="plan".
Now I want to get the "plan" and "user" between the 2 slash in the url to identify which section I'm in and to let accordion decide which will be collapses.

**Example**: if I'm in user section, the accordion which had id="plan" will be collapse.

Is it possible to do that? Or have any better way to identify which accordion must be collapsed?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if(url.split('?')[1].split('/')[1] == "user"){
   $('#user').collapse(); // this is pseudo code
}
else{
   $('#plan').collapse(); // this is pseudo code
}
```

Comment: glad to have helped;)